# Problemas con inyeccion de servicio de una libreria en Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, servicio, constructor, libreria

Estoy trabajando con angular 16.2 y quiero crear un servicio que tiene en el contructor la inyección de otro servicio, esto es en una libreria. El codigo es muy sencillo, solo es esto y el problema esta en el constructor del servicio ya que así no funciona:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpStrategy } from './auth/strategy/http-strategy';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthLibService {

  // Definir la URL base de la API de Laravel
  private baseURL = "http://localhost:8000/api";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

    console.log('prueba authlibservice');

   }

}
```

**Pero con el constructor así si funciona:**

```
constructor( ) {
   console.log('prueba authlibservice');
}
```

El código que exporta de la api:

```
/*
 * Public API Surface of auth-lib
 */

export * from './lib/auth-lib.service';
export * from './lib/auth-lib.component';
export * from './lib/auth-lib.module';
```

Y el modulo de la libreria tiene

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthLibComponent } from './auth-lib.component';
import { SanctumStrategy } from './auth/strategy/SanctumStrategy';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthLibService } from './auth-lib.service';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AuthLibComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  exports: [
    AuthLibComponent
  ],
  providers: [ AuthLibService ]
})
export class AuthLibModule { }
```

Y este servicio le quiero usasr en mi proyecto inyectandolo así en un componente:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthLibService, SanctumStrategy } from 'auth-lib';
import { PruebaService } from '../prueba.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-prueba',
  templateUrl: './prueba.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./prueba.component.scss']
})
export class PruebaComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private authLib: AuthLibService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log( );

  }

}
```

Al ejecutar eeste codigo en el navegador me devuelve este error:

> main.ts:6 ERROR Error: NG0203: inject() must be called from an
> injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field
> initializer, or a function used with `runInInjectionContext`. Find
> more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0203
> at injectInjectorOnly (core.mjs:731:15)
> at Module.ɵɵinject (core.mjs:744:60)
> at Object.AuthLibService_Factory [as factory] (auth-lib.service.ts:11:28)
> at core.mjs:9432:43
> at runInInjectorProfilerContext (core.mjs:694:9)
> at R3Injector.hydrate (core.mjs:9431:17)
> at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:9301:33)
> at ChainedInjector.get (core.mjs:14001:36)
> at lookupTokenUsingModuleInjector (core.mjs:4504:39)
> at getOrCreateInjectable (core.mjs:4552:12)

y por último **si el servicio se encuentra dentro de mi proyecto y no en la libreria** funciona correctamente.

Sabe alguien donde puede estar el problema?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Resolví esto añadiendo en el fichero angular.json:

```
"preserveSymlinks": true,
```